# Firebase Swift -How to Listen for 2 separate events on .childAdded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My db structure is

```
-ref
   -uid_ABC // listener starts here
       -uid_1 (existing)
          -firebaseKey917: 1
          -firebaseKeyXYZ: 1 
          // ...
       -uid_2 (existing)
          -firebaseKeyQRS: 1
          -firebaseKey123: 1 
          // ...
```

**How can I add a .childListener to listen for 2 separate events at once on the same *uid_ABC* node**:

1- Every time a new k/v pair is added to the the existing users? For example if uid_1 or uid_2 added a new k/v

```
-uid_1
   // ...
   -firebaseKey000: 1 // newly added
```

2- Every time a new user is added? For example if uid_3 was added with  their k/v pair, I would know

```
-uid_3 // newly added
   -firebaseKey345: 1
```

My ultimate goal is to get all the newly added firebaseKeys under uid_ABC's children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database's child listeners fire events on the direct child nodes under the level where you attach them.

So there is no way to get `child_` events for your lowest level children, if you attach a single listener to `uid_ABC`. Similarly, if you attach listeners to `uid_ABC/uid_1` and `uid_ABC/uid_2`, you will not get `child_` events for new peer nodes of those listeners.

The two options I can think of:

- Attach a single listener to `uid_ABC`, and figure out the changes to the lower level in your own application code.
- Attach listeners to both `uid_ABC` and the child nodes under it. This should not result in duplicate reads, as the SDK deduplicate the overlapping branches under the hood anyway.

Comment: I figured that I had to use separate listeners, I was hoping theire was a more compact way. Thanks for your help :)